# Mi codigo para hacer mover mi personaje no funciona

Tags: unity2d

No puedo hacer que el personaje se mueva con teclas, soy nuevo en C# y no se como arreglarlo, Aqui el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes agregado un Rigidbody a tu personaje?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código para que podamos ayudarte. [ask] - [tour]

Comment: No todos pueden ver las imágenes: pon el código _como texto, con formato. Y como te han mencionado, lee [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Si no tienes agregado el `componente RigidBody` a tu personaje, debes de agregarlo, una vez que tengas ya este componente, en la clase en la que estás añadiendo el código pon esto:

```
public class PlayerControl2D : MonoBehaivour {

  public float force = 150;
  Rigidbody rb;     

  void Start(){
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>() 
   }

 void Update(){
     float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

     Vector3 vector = new Vector3(h, 0.5f, v);

     rb.AddForce(vector*force*Time.deltatime);
   }
 }
```

Luego de esto asignas el `script` a tu player y debería funcionar tu movimiento.

Comment: Lo intentare, Gracias

Comment: si te ayudó la respuesta?